# How to POST REST API Messages from oozie workflows

Tags: apache-spark, oozie

I have an workflow which looks like below.

```
start = fork1
<fork1/>
   <action1>
   <action2>
 <fork1>
 <join1 to fork2>
  <fork2/>
    <action3>
   <action4>
  <fork2>..

....
....
<join 75 to fork 76>
 <fork76>
     <action 987>
     <action 988>
  <fork76/>
 <join 76 to "END">
```

Each action has 2 end nodes.

I would like to modify the same in below way.

```
<OK > to post a "SUCCESS" message to REST endpoint and then to proceed to next_join_number.
<ERROR> to post "FAILURE" message to REST endpoint and then to proceed email & kill action.
```

But I am unsure how to make this as generic & acheive it .Only way  I can think of is to write 988 separate actions to send status messages and appending to  action.

Comment: Use shell action and send message from shell script

Comment: @Srinivas shell action would not be great option. As if you trigger a spark job using shell action, and you want to kill your whole oozie workflow, your spark job will not get killed.

Comment: His question is he want to post message to some reset end point success or failure ..I was telling him to use shell action to invoke rest API with message

Comment: You can handle killing spark job once your oozie workflow killed..write shell action use yarn command to kill spark job.

Comment: @Srinivas Sorry I misunderstood. But in that case you have to write separate shell action after each join (as his requirement)

Comment: Np.. May be your answer is correct if you can add invoking reset api in shell action.. change if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sub-workflow for each action.

Each action (lets say Spark) will have a separate workflow. And in that you will have 2 extra action (probably a Shell action).

```xml
<workflow-app name="spark-subworkflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    ... # configs
    <start to="special-spark"/>
    <action name="special-spark">
        <spark>
            ...
        </spark>
        <ok to="send-success"/>
        <error to="send-failure"/>
    </action>
    <action name="send-success">
        <shell>
            <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
            <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
            <exec>script-to-run.sh</exec>
            <env-var>MESSAGE_TO_SEND=SUCCESS</env-var>
            <file>hdfs:///path-to-script/your-rest-script.sh#script-to-run.sh</file>
        </shell>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="end"/>
    </action>
    <action name="send-failure">
        <shell>
            <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
            <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
            <exec>script-to-run.sh</exec>
            <env-var>MESSAGE_TO_SEND=FAILURE</env-var>
            <file>hdfs:///path-to-script/your-rest-script.sh#script-to-run.sh</file>
        </shell>
        <ok to="kill"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
</workflow-app>
```

Kind of this way you need to replace your each action. Parameterise the sub-workflow so that it can be reused for same type of action.

Notice that I have created 2 action, one from success and one for failure. Thats because if the action which is sending the status failed you want your workflow to continue. So for error/no-error of `send-success` action your workflow should continue; same for `send-failure`, it will kill the sub-workflow.

I tried to achieve it using [Decision Node](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node). But no luck. So only option to create 2 separate action. Even thought you can use same script `your-rest-script.sh` as `MESSAGE_TO_SEND` is the parameter for both the action. Using java/python-shell action the flow would be same.